# Write multiple lines with cat using a loop in shell

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I have this script

```
 for ((i=0 ; $i<=$c ; i++))
 do
 cat <<"EOF" >my_file.html
 line 1
 line 2
 ...
 EOF
 done
```

It is supposed to  write some specific lines in each loop but my file is empty and i always get this error

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Before this loop i have another use of cat exactly like this

```
cat <<"EOF" >my_file.html
line1
...
line n
EOF
```

After running the script my_file.html contains these n lines but none of the loop lines.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong.

You have a space before the *delimiter* denoting the end of here-doc.

```
 cat <<"EOF" >my_file.html
 line 1
 line 2
 ...
EOF     # Remove the leading space from this line.
```

---

Additionally, if you want to redirect within a loop you probably wanted to *append* `>>` instead of redirecting `>`.

Comment: @user3301045 Yes, that's because you have a space before `EOF` (see edit above.

Comment: @user3301045 Show your script.  There should be errors elsewhere.

Comment: @user3301045 As mentioned in the answer, you use `>` which truncates the file.  In order to __append__ to the file, use `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have any whitespace before or after the `EOF` delimiter, otherwise the shell won't be able to find the end of the here-document and you will get an `unexpected end of file` error.

This line should only contain the delimiter word (`EOF`) and nothing else. Not even comments.

```
cat <<"EOF" >my_file.html
line 1
line 2
EOF
# there should not be any whitespace around EOF on the line above
```